# Running JMeter test plan with Ant is not working

Tags: ant, jmeter

I am trying to integrate JMeter with ant. Below is the script. For some reason it is not executing any of the targets. I do not get any error when I run the script. Even a simple clean operation is not getting executed. Is there something am I missing?

```
<project name="Performance Testing for my project" basedir="C:\apache-ant-1.9.2" >

  <target name="clean" >
    <delete includeemptydirs="true">    
      <fileset dir="${basedir}/Results/" excludes="**/PerformanceCharts.html"/>
    </delete>
  </target>

  <target name="run-jmeter" depends="clean" >
    <taskdef name="jmeter" classpath="${basedir}\apache-jmeter-2.10\extras\ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar"
             classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"/>
  <echo message="Hello, world"/>
    <jmeter
            jmeterhome="${basedir}\apache-jmeter-2.10"
            resultlog="${basedir}\Results\JMeterResults.xml">
      <testplans dir="${basedir}\TestPlan" includes="*.jmx"/>
      <property name="request.threads" value="1"/>
      <property name="request.loop" value="10"/>
    </jmeter>
  </target>

  <target name="create-reports" depends="run-jmeter">
    <xslt
            in="${basedir}\Results\JMeterResults.xml"
            out="${basedir}\Results\JMeterResults.html"
            style="${basedir}\apache-jmeter-2.10\extras\jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl"/>
  </target> 

  <target name="main" depends="clean,run-jmeter,create-reports"/>
</project>
```

my directory structure on my project is

```
C:\apache-ant-1.9.2
    |
    ------apache-jmeter-2.10
    |
    ------Results
    |
    ------TestPlan
```

the "basedir" i tried with "." and with "C:\apache-ant-1.9.2"

I am running this on a window 8 box.

This is what i get when i run the script

```
C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin>ant -buildfile jmeterRun.xml
Buildfile: C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin\jmeterRun.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: What is your default target? Why didn't you set main as default one?

Comment: It's quite quite odd to have the basedir set to the ant installation, why are you doing this?

Comment: What's the error? Build Successful, but tests were not executed, right?

Comment: You can more detailed steps here - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a target, as your project has no default target.
try running 
`ant main` from the commandline
and then adding `default="main"` to the `<project>` element so you don't have to specify this.

Comment: thanks i am new to ant and jmeter. what is the best way to set basedir

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="performance-tests" default="run-performance-tests" basedir=".">
<property name="jmeter.home" value="${basedir}/apache-jmeter-2.10" />           

    <path id="jmeter.path">
      <fileset dir="D:\apache-jmeter-2.10\extras" includes="\*.jar" />
    </path> 

    <target name="run-performance-tests">
      <delete dir="${basedir}/target" quiet="true" failonerror="false"/>
<mkdir dir="${basedir}/target"/>
      <taskdef name="jmeter" classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask" classpathref="jmeter.path" />
      <echo message="Running load tests in testing.xml"/>
      <jmeter
       jmeterhome="D:\apache-jmeter-2.10"
        resultlog="${basedir}/target/JMeterResults.xml">
        <jvmarg value="-Xincgc"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Dproperty=value"/>
        <property name="request.threads" value="5"/>
        <property name="request.loop" value="50"/>
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
        <testplans dir="${basedir}/TestPlan" includes="RiponAlWasim_One.jmx"/>
      </jmeter>
      <xslt in="${basedir}/target/JMeterResults.xml"
        out="${basedir}/target/Result_One.html"
        style="${basedir}/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked like a charm, I appreciate the clarity on the build file, it took just minutes to see my test running..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="performance-tests" default="run-performance-tests" basedir=".">
    <property name="jmeter.home" value="${basedir}/apache-jmeter-2.9" />
    <path id="jmeter.path">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/apache-jmeter-2.9/extras" includes="\*.jar" />
    </path>
    <target name="run-performance-tests">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/target" quiet="true" failonerror="false"/>
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target"/>
        <taskdef name="jmeter" classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask" classpathref="jmeter.path" />
        <echo message="Running load tests in testing.xml"/>
        <jmeter
       jmeterhome="${basedir}/apache-jmeter-2.9"
        resultlog="${basedir}/target/JMeterResults.xml">
            <jvmarg value="-Xincgc"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dproperty=value"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
            <testplans dir="${basedir}/TestPlan" includes="GetSS4.jmx"/>
        </jmeter>
        <xslt in="${basedir}/target/JMeterResults.xml"
        out="${basedir}/target/Result_One.html"
        style="${basedir}/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

I have made some simple changes to the build file where the hard coded file paths are replaced with dynamic values.

But how do I get the TPS values from the results, I only see the average time and the percentage of successful requests.